# MySQL datetime operation

Tags: mysql, datetime

How to get the datetime value several days/weeks/months/years later in MySQL?

I just know the current datetime is NOW() .

Comment: Heh.  I didn't notice it was him until I saw your comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT NOW() + INTERVAL 3 DAY
SELECT NOW() + INTERVAL 5 WEEK
SELECT NOW() + INTERVAL 6 MONTH
SELECT NOW() + INTERVAL 2 YEAR
```

Answer (score 2):

See the mysql [time functions reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html)